# MVC 2 - Display first result only in for each loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, viewmodel

I've got what appears to be a fairly basic loop:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model.Items.OrderByDescending(b => b.ItemDateTime)) {%>
```

Instead of looping through all the items I just want to output the first item, how can I do this?

Comment: Felipe Oriani's solution works but, in keeping with MVC design principles, you should resolve this issue before you load the view (i.e. somewhere in the model layer, though not necessarily in the view model which should contain mostly (if not entirely) POCOs). Smart views are an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Felipe's comment, it's better design usually to put things like this in your view models or controllers, not the views.

You could put this on your viewmodel

```
public Item EarliestItem
{
    get { return Items.OrderByDescending(b => b.ItemDateTime).FirstOrDefault(); }
}
```

Then use this in your view

Or whatever it is you want to do with the earliest item.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `FirstODefault()` method of your collection. Try something like this:

```
// check if the model contains any item
if (Model.Items.Count() > 0)
{
    //show the item...
    var firstItem = Model.Items.OrderByDescending(b => b.ItemDateTime).FirstOrDefault();
}
```